# cakephp 3 save empty belongsToMany relation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-3.4

I have a `Shops` table which can have `Products`. Other Shops can have the same Products so I used a `belongsToMany` relation table `ShopsProducts`.

I can add an infinite number of Products to a Shop and remove them by saving the Shop entity including the relation.
All works fine, but if I want to unlink all Products from a Shop in my form and save, the relation is of cause empty so the Shop will always have 1 Product that I can't delete over the relation but only directly.

This is what the request looks like from the Shops form with a Product

```
data => [
    'name' => 'some',
    'is_active' => '1',
    'slug' => 'some',
    'product_id' => '',
    'products' => [
        (int) 5 => [
            'id' => '5',
            '_joinData' => [
                'priority' => '0'
            ]
        ]
    ],
]
```

And this is the request without

```
data => [
    'name' => 'some',
    'is_active' => '1',
    'slug' => 'some',
    'product_id' => '',
]
```

**What is the cake way to handle this issue?**

Comment: So what is the exact problem then ? Do you want to delete all products related to shops ? and then sometimes shops might not have products ??

Comment: When in the Shop form I want to be able to uncheck all Products from that Shop and save
But if I do so, the relation is empty so there are noch changes that could be saved

Comment: and are you searching for something that will save that empty data ?

Comment: I want to save my Shop entity and if the Products relation is empty (because I unselected all) I want all relations in ShopsProducts to be deleted

Answer (score 1):

What's your save strategy?

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations

Try `replace` instead of `append`.

If that doesn't work for you, check in the before() or afterSave() if products->get('products') is empty, if it is manually call a deleteAll() on the join table for that product an shop.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your association to [] to blank it out.

```
$shops->products = [];

$shops->setDirty('products ', true);
```